# running amd64 application on i686 machine that support CPU op-mode(s): 32-bit, 64-bit (lscpu confirms) using QEMU. My OS ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, package-management, qemu

I am trying to run my amd64 app on my i686 that supports CPU op-mode(s) 32-bit and 64-bit using QEMU.

I've got an error:

```
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: No such file or directory
```

I print command `sudo qemu-x86_64 appname`

My OS Ubuntu 16.04.

Can't find and install that library on Ubuntu.